# Killed 20.04 upgrade during "processing triggers" - how to tell if I'm in a good state?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I was upgrading my desktop from 18.04 to 20.04. Everything went smoothly, but then during the cleanup phase, it got stuck on "processing triggers for wine" for a really long time.

I noticed CPU was high for hidpi-daemon, and focal. I killed the first, thinking it was impinging, and then when nothing happened, I killed `focal`, which is the upgrade itself.

I then ran `apt remove wine` because TBH I don't really use it these days so might as well uproot it for now. It removed like 1+GB of stuff, so I wonder if that's just finishing up the cleanup that I had interrupted.

I then ran a regular update using software updater, and rebooted. It had a "failed to unmount /home" error during shutdown, but then it looks like I've successfully booted into 20.04.

Am I at risk of being in some kind of half-installed subtly-broken state, or am I good? What can I do to finish any remaining cleanup, and validate that things are really good to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Think it better to backup data and do clean install.  Clean up should be near end, but unknown if old/unused programs left to upset future updates.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I also got this, and eventually (after clicking wait about 20 times), I got through the "processing triggers for wine" stage and the upgrade (to 22.04) was able to continue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1246812)

Comment: True, but if someone searches and finds this like I did, it may help keep them from getting into the original poster's predicament.